# How to prevent use my API which gives data for my React app

Tags: reactjs, api, security

I make a web service and I'm going to use a React. A data for the service will be fetch from my API.

But there is a simple way to find out which endpoints I'm using, and what data I'm sending. This knowledge gives a lot options to make bots for my service.

**Is there any option to prevent this?**

I know, I can require a signing all requests, but it's also easy to get to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done. Whatever is done in client-side JavaScript, can be reverse-engineered and simulated.

Efforts should be focused on preventing API from being abused, i.e. throttling or blacklisting clients based on their activity or available information (user agent, suspicious request, generated traffic). If the use of API allows captcha, suspicious clients can be asked for proving their humaneness.

There are half-measures that can be applied to client side application and make it less advantageous for abuse (and also for development).

*Prevent unauthorized access to unminified/unobfuscated JS AND source maps*. There may be a need to authorize them on per user basis. This will make debugging and bug reporting more difficult

*Hard-code parts that are involved in request signing to browser APIs*, e.g.:

```
apiKey = hash(NOT_SO_SECRET_KEY + document.querySelector('.varyingBlock').innerHTML)
```

This requires bots to emulate browser environment and makes their work much less efficient. This also affects the design of the application in negative way. Obviously, there will be additional difficulties with SSR and it won't translate to native platforms easily.

Answer (score 1):

here two basic preventive measures that you can use.

1. Captcha 

   Use a captcha service like [recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html). so that user can use your website only after passing the captcha test. Its highly difficult for bots to pass the captchas.
2. Rate Limit Api usage.

   Add rate limiting to your api. so that a logged in user can only make 100 requests in 10 minutes, the numbers will depend on you use case